# Android keyboard InputType without EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

For an android app with a custom design, I open the keyboard manually as it have no input on which to focus.

I open it using :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

I would like to set the keyboard as InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER but can't found any documentation on how to do this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't know why you'd want the keyboard to be open when there's no place for its input to go, but maybe it would work to create a "dummy" edittext, set its input type to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER, point the keyboard to it and set its visibility to View.GONE?

Comment: It's because I will use image instead of the inputtext. I will try your solution, I didn't know I could set focus on an invisible edittext.

Comment: I can't get the focus when edittext visibility is set to gone, any other suggestion?

Comment: I guess you could try setting setFocusable(true) and setFocusableInTouchMode(true). Or instead of setting the visibility to gone you could try setting the height and width to 0. But honestly, at this point I'm just shooting in the dark, so your guess is as good as mine ...

Comment: I just solved the problem by set "Gone" visibility on the linearlayout containing all of the EditText. Thanks Andy for your time. Do you know if I should delete this question as I cannot set any "solved" flag?

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! I'd say just leave this question as it is so that if others have a similar problem they'll be able to see how you solved it.

Comment: You can also answer your own question! You helped me, do it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to set all the edittext in in a LinearLayout and to set visibility to "Gone" on that LinearLayout and not on the EditText(s).

This way you can still focus on the EditText programmatically by doing a click on any other element.

Comment: It is a shame that you cannot get input while not having an EditText. I want to redirect my text to and use the onCreateInputConnection() mechanism for this. Thanks for being able to hide this EditText!

Comment: Oh wow this EditText requirement is crazy.  I was fighting this for an hour before hitting this.  Thank you.